# sh file in terminal outputting odd processes

Tags: html, shell, logging, rust, terminal

so this code is written by someone else (https://github.com/AnyTimeTraveler/pipes-and-rust) using HTML RUST and SHELL, and I have no clue how it is supposed to work. However, I know that it is supposed to install a software through terminal, and running it from terminal I get the following log which went to a stale:

`    [main 2023-03-14T04:14:22.384Z] update#setState idle

```
[main 2023-03-14T04:14:23.064Z] [UtilityProcess id: 1, type: extensionHost, pid: <none>]: creating new...

[main 2023-03-14T04:14:23.076Z] [UtilityProcess id: 1, type: extensionHost, pid: 22148]: successfully created

[main 2023-03-14T04:14:52.400Z] update#setState checking for updates

[main 2023-03-14T04:14:52.425Z] update#setState idle

[8152:0313/211622.415:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(481)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is`
```

This is the source code:
`    #!/usr/bin/env sh

```
# Set hostname or ip address of your reMarkable
host="remarkable"
port="22"


echo "Creating /opt/ directory, if it doesn't exist, yet.."
ssh "$host" "mkdir -p /opt/" || exit 1
echo "Done"

echo "Stopping previous version, if it exists..."
ssh "$host" "systemctl stop pipes-and-rust.service"
ssh "$host" "killall pipes-and-rust"
echo "Done"

echo "Copying files to device..."
scp "./pipes-and-rust" "$host:/opt/pipes-and-rust" || exit 1
sed "s/PORT=80/PORT=${port}/" -i "./pipes-and-rust.service"
scp "./pipes-and-rust.service" "$host:/lib/systemd/system/pipes-and-rust.service" || exit 1
echo "Done"

echo "Installing service..."
ssh "$host" "systemctl daemon-reload" || exit 1
ssh "$host" "systemctl enable pipes-and-rust.service" || exit 1
ssh "$host" "systemctl start pipes-and-rust.service" || exit 1
echo "Done"

echo
echo "pipes-and-rust has been successfully installed on your device!"`
```

It is confusing and worrying, hopefully if someone can point out my ignorance of something common.

I tried to modify the variable through visual studio code but nothing seemed to change.

Answer (score 0):

Since windows terminal does not natively support .sh file, it just goes off doing random stuff. The script in the .sh file is likely ignored. I tried creating an empty .sh file and ran it in terminal and yielded similar result.